# Overriding third-party method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, overriding, rest-client

I'm developing some tool using pure ruby and RestClient and I'd like to override default log_request method of Request class.

lib/restclient/request.rb

```
module RestClient
  class Request
    def log_request
      RestClient.log << "SECRET"
    end
  end
end
```

But now, if I try to test this, it is not working:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'restclient'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> RestClient.log = "stdout"
=> "stdout"
irb(main):003:0> RestClient.get("http://localhost")
RestClient.get "http://localhost", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"
```

Expected to see only `SECRET` as output.

I'm probably missing, how to "inject" my code in default RestClient library ?

How can I do this from another file in lib/mytool/somefile.rb ?

Comment: The problem is that the monkey patch is not loaded. You need to require request.rb somewhere.

Comment: I found out, that `require 'restclient/request'` was not enough, because it was already encountered, by `require 'restclient'`. Correct solution was `load 'lib/restclient/request.rb'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file need to be exactly required after `require 'restclient'` 
Adding `load 'lib/restclient/request.rb'` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Since you place it in your lib folder, this file is never being loaded as RestClient::Request constant is already defined. Place this code inside your config/initializers folder

Comment: But this is not a rails app... I don't have such thing as config/initalizers folder

Comment: Ah, are you sure then that this file is loaded? Add `raise 'blah'` at the start of the file and check whether it's being hit